# SplitButton does not close the dropdownitems once clicked

Tags: syncfusion

I am using component SfSplitButton of Blazor Syncfusion version 19.2.48 in razor page as below:

```
<SfSplitButton Content="Downloads"
                              Disabled="IsDownloadReportButtonDisabled"
                              CssClass="mr-2">
                   <SplitButtonEvents ItemSelected="OnDownloadReportItemSelected"></SplitButtonEvents>
                   <DropDownMenuItems>
                       <DropDownMenuItem Id="DownloadTcaReportItem" Text="Download Report"></DropDownMenuItem>
                       <DropDownMenuItem Id="DownloadTcaConsentReportItem" Text="Download Consent"></DropDownMenuItem>
                       @if (_isAccountOccupationalHealth)
                       {
                           <DropDownMenuItem Id="DownloadTcaSummaryReportItem" Text="Download Summary Report"></DropDownMenuItem>
                       }

                   </DropDownMenuItems>
               </SfSplitButton>
@code{
  private async Task OnDownloadReportItemSelected(MenuEventArgs args)
    {       
        switch (args.Item.Id)
        {
            case "DownloadTcaReportItem":
                //Do some task

                break;
            case "DownloadTcaSummaryReportItem":
                //Do some task

                break;
            case "DownloadTcaConsentReportItem":
               //Do some task

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[after click on dropdown items still showing in the other pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAjvy.png)